# zfs errors on hetzner cloud ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I have an ubuntu 22.04 system on hetzner cloud arm machines that keeps experiencing zfs errors, and I am a bit stumped as to what is the problem.

```
zpool status -v
  pool: encpool
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
    corruption.  Applications may be affected.
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
    entire pool from backup.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:02:09 with 0 errors on Sun Feb  4 20:53:31 2024
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    encpool     ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sda     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: Permanent errors have been detected in the following files:

        <0xe16d>:<0x0>
```

It usually shows up as above. I did zfs scrub encpool and when it completed first time it was showing the same error. Then I reran it and now it shows as OK:

```
zpool status -v
  pool: encpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:01:56 with 0 errors on Sun Feb  4 21:02:48 2024
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    encpool     ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz1-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sda     ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

This has now happened a few times already. scrub sometimes helps immediately, sometimes after 2 runs.

sdx disks are hetzner cloud volumes, which should themselves be redundant ( every block of data is stored on three different physical servers ).
encpool is encrypted and compression is turned on, but not dedup. it's configured as raidz1.

```
zpool list -v
NAME        SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
encpool    59.5G  48.1G  11.4G        -         -    53%    80%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
  raidz1-0  59.5G  48.1G  11.4G        -         -    53%  80.8%      -    ONLINE
    sdb        -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
    sdd        -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
    sda        -      -      -        -         -      -      -      -    ONLINE
zfs version
zfs-2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.2
zfs-kmod-2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using multiple devices in the zpool for a cloud instance like this?

Comment: I've experienced some data corruption when just using one volume, so I don't trust it anymore. but as seen, the corruption still creeps up somehow, even with three, although so far it was never in an actual file